# Can't display sub-menu for custom ActionProvider

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've created a custom `ActionProvider` that I want to use to show a sub-menu for sorting, similar visually to `ShareActionProvider`. The action view displays as expected, but clicking on the icon doesn't display the sub-menu or show any visual feedback (pressed state) at all. I'm using the support v7 library for backward compatibility action bar. Is there an implementation I am missing to display the menu?

ActionProvider:

```
public class SortActionProvider extends ActionProvider implements OnMenuItemClickListener {

    private Context mContext;

    public SortActionProvider(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView(){
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_sort_by_size);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasSubMenu(){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareSubMenu(SubMenu subMenu){
        subMenu.clear();

        subMenu.add("Sort by name").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        subMenu.add("Sort by type").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "I was clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:support="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_sort"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.myapp.provider.SortActionProvider"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/sort"
        support:actionProviderClass="com.myapp.provider.SortActionProvider"
        support:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `onPrepareSubMenu()` is only called when `onCreateActionView()` returns null. Your solution (attaching a `PopupMenu` to the `ImageView`) will work, but since your `ImageView` is displaying an icon, you might consider just setting the icon in the menu XML and getting rid of the `ImageView`:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_sort"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_sort_by_size"
      android:title="@string/sort"
      support:actionProviderClass="com.myapp.provider.SortActionProvider"
      support:showAsAction="always" />
```

and then:

```
@Override
public View onCreateActionView(){
    return null;
}
```

This should also solve the problem with no visual feedback for touch states - the problem being that your ImageView is not configured to do anything with touch states.

Comment: Great, didn't know that was a stipulation. Do you know if this will also show the arrow in the bottom-right corner that signifies it displays a menu, or does that need to be provided in the drawable resource?

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be part of the drawable resource. Here's the drawable  ShareActionProvider uses, for reference: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_menu_share_holo_light.png

Comment: Also make sure proguard is not removing the class in actionProviderClass (won't be referenced from any other Java code). Took me a while to figure this out, add "keep public class com.myapp.provider.SortActionProvider { *; }" to your proguard config if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The `ActionProvider` doesn't show the sub-menu when you click on the action view. I'm actually not sure under what conditions the sub-menu is displayed. What I had to do was attach a `PopupMenu` to the action view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateActionView(){
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_sort_by_size);

    final PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(mContext, imageView);
    menu.inflate(R.menu.sort_options_menu);
    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            menu.show();
        }
    });

    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, a good option if ou still want to show a custom view for ActionPovider