# Android ActionBar ActionProvider submenu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I just can't get the ActionProvider to show a submenu and I don't undestand why. I have my menu defined in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
        android:id="@+id/dossier_menu"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.some.other.mockup.MActionProvider">
</item>
</menu>
```

action provider class:

```
public class MActionProvider extends ActionProvider  {

private static final String TAG = "MActionProvider";
private static final int LIST_LENGTH = 3;
private Context context;

/**
 * Creates a new instance.
 *
 * @param context Context for accessing resources.
 */
public MezzActionProvider(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateActionView() {
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.action_layout, null);
    //view must be returned not tetxView or just buttonView
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean hasSubMenu() {
    Log.d(TAG, "hasSubMenu");
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onPerformDefaultAction() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPerformDefaultAction");
    return super.onPerformDefaultAction();
}

/**add submenu in code**/
@Override
public void onPrepareSubMenu(SubMenu subMenu) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareSubMenu");

    subMenu.clear();
    subMenu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 1,"Mezz 1");
    subMenu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 2, "Mezz 2");

}

}
```

and action layout is:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mezz State ++"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"/>
```

I tried using button instead of image view, even tried adding submenu to the menu item in xml, when I click on the action provider it just doesn't show any submenu I can't figure out why.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer here:

[Can't display sub-menu for custom ActionProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439106/cant-display-sub-menu-for-custom-actionprovider)

Problem is my onCreateActionView() method doesn't return null.

So thanks to Jason Robinson answer here is how:

```
@Override
public View onCreateActionView() {
  View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.action_layout, null);

  final PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
  menu.inflate(R.menu.submenu);
  menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

  view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        menu.show();
    }
  });

return view;
}
```

and submenu.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/mezzSub1"
            android:title="Mezz 1"
            android:showAsAction="always"></item>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/mezzSub2"
            android:title="Mezz 2"
            android:showAsAction="always"></item>

</menu>
```